# CX-20 Quadcopter Part

Tags: capacitor, resistors, motor, components, motor-controller

One of the ESC's on my quadcopter is missing a component. I am unsure what this component does or where to find a new part. Is it a sort of resistor?? What size? it features no markings that I can see. I have attached images of the working esc and of the esc with the missing part. (See arrows)

[image: Identical working ESC]

[image: Missing Part]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a multilayer ceramic capacitor, being used to bypass across the heavy red and black leads connected to the end of the board.

It's hard to guess the actual specifications without knowing more about the controller, but I'd bet that it's somewhere in the range of 1 to 10 µF, and rated to withstand whatever voltage is on those leads (with a comfortable margin).

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way I can figure out more about the specs? Such as the µF? Upon testing the voltage it is 12.2v. Im sure it is mandatory to make sure this capacitor matches the others in order for all 4 esc's to run the same?

Comment: No, it is just a power supply filter, it only really matters that the voltage rating is sufficient and the *effective*  capacitance is large *enough* to get the job done, not exactly what it is.  Do exercise care in selection though, as if you have a multi-cell pack powering this thing the voltage may be high enough that some multi layer ceramics may see their effective capacitance sharply reduced even if their voltage rating is far from being exceeded.